# Changing contents of a multiple select (HTML) using query's load() and the span

Tags: jquery, select, load, html

I would like to have a list of clients in a separate HTML file on my server that I can load with jquery and put into a multiple select drop down.

```
var clientList = document.getElementById(clientList);
$('#clientList').load('clients.html');
```

My clients file is in the following format stored as an HTML file with no headers with the name clients.html

```
<option value="address1">name1</input>
<option value="address2">name2</input>
<option value="address3">name3</input>
<option value="address4">name4</input>
```

In my body I have this

```
<b>Waypoints:</b> <br />
<i>(Ctrl-Click for multiple selection)</i> <br />
<select multiple id="waypoints">
<span id="clientList"></span>   
</select>
```

But it doesn't work. If I put it in a different span then it will display on the screen but I can't seem to get it to go into the span for my multiple select box.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Does `$('#waypoints').load('clients.html');` work? The `.load()` function drops the response *inside* the target element; it doesn't *replace* the target.  In other words, the target is treated as a container and the response replaces the current contents.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

jquery .load() loads the content into the matched element. try this `$('#waypoints').load('clients.html');` and remove the span

Comment: Unfortunately this didn't make it work. My multiple select box is now blank.

Comment: I would like it to produce something like this; except dynamically

`<b>Waypoints:</b> <br />
<i>(Ctrl-Click for multiple selection)</i> <br />
<select multiple id="waypoints">
<option value="address1">name1</input>
<option value="address2">name2</input>
<option value="address3">name3</input>
<option value="address4">name4</input>  
</select>`

Comment: are you using firebug? can you check if the ajax call actually returns content?

Comment: If I replace the select with just a div then it fills in the text of my HTML file. It reads my file just doesn't stick anything in my select.

Comment: can you put the select inside a div and add the select tags inside clients.html? and then use the load function on the div